# Embed a celery worker in my own code

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I have a service that needs a sort of coordinator component. The coordinator will manage entities that need to be assigned to users, taken away from users if the users do not respond on a timely manner, and also handle user responses if they do response. The coordinator will also need to contact messaging services to notify the users they have something to handle.

I want the coordinator to be a single-threaded process, as the load is not expected to be too much for the first few years of usage, and I'd much rather postpone all the concurrency issues to when I really need to handle them (if at all).

The coordinator will receive new entities and user responses from a Django webserver. I thought the easiest way to handle this is with Celery tasks - the webserver just starts a task that the coordinator consumes on its own time.

For this to happen, I need the coordinator to contain a celery worker, and replace the current worker mainloop with my own version (one that checks the broker for a new message and handles the scheduling).

How feasible is it? The alternative is to avoid Celery and use RabbitMQ directly. I'd rather not do that.

Comment: Could you please provide more detailed information. I can't get why you really need to replace main loop.

Comment: I want the worker to handle incoming tasks, as well as various scheduling events.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this names: coordinator with rabbitmq (or some other broker kombu supports) and users with celery workers.

I am pretty sure you can do all you need (and much more) just by configuring celery / kombu and rabbitmq and without writing too many (if any) lines of code.

small note: Celery features scheduled tasks.